# How to extend Powershell runspace with RestrictedLanguage to allow usage of additional types

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a Powershell host application where I create a runspace with the following code:

```
var iss = InitialSessionState.Create();
iss.LanguageMode = PSLanguageMode.RestrictedLanguage;
iss.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true; // otherwise silently fails in loading incorrect module

// See http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2012/02/10/Bypassing-Restricted-Execution-Policy-in-Code-or-in-Script
iss.AuthorizationManager = new System.Management.Automation.AuthorizationManager(null); // no execution policy
// Create the runspace and stuff.
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(host, iss))
{
    runspace.Open();
    :
}
```

This is perfect, I can extend the set of supported cmdlets with iis.Commands.Add(), and preload existing modules using iss.ImportPSModulesFromPath().

But how can I add additional types that can be used as well in the runspace? I tried:

```
iss.Assemblies.Add(new List<SessionStateAssemblyEntry>()
        {
            new SessionStateAssemblyEntry("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO"),
            new SessionStateAssemblyEntry("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended"),
        };
```

And then access methods on these assemblies.But I get the error that I can only call methods on core types.

If I use language mode FullLanguage it works, but then I can also execute things like:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText('c:\test.txt', 'hello world!')
```